# How to make the Edit User Profile to have all tabs in one page?

Tags: users, routes

If I load this page
http://domain.com/user/1/edit

I have on top more tabs that I have to unify into one page

I've added some custom fields to the user profile that adds some more tabs when I go into

http://domain.com/admin/user/profile

so that adds the tabs that I need to appear in the same page as http://domain.com/user/1/edit

how can I do that?

note that I'm using Drupal 6.19

Comment: Could you maybe edit the question so that it's more of a...well...question?

Also, please add Drupal version and any modules you are using for your user profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [One page profile](http://drupal.org/project/onepageprofile) module should do this if you're using the core Profile module.